# upload stopwords and synonyms to Elasticsearch cloud server

Tags: elasticsearch

I have deployed my Elasticsearch server to the cloud: [cloud.elastic.co](https://cloud.elastic.co/deployments)

I have seen [stopwords](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/using-stopwords.html) and [synonyms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html) documentation, which explain stopwords.txt/synonyms.txt files could be copied under *config* folder... but how can I do this on a cloud server?

---

I know I can pass the stopwords in an array, but using a file, [it would be easier to update them](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/using-stopwords.html#updating-stopwords):

> Updating stopwords is easier if you specify them in a file with the
>   stopwords_path parameter. You can just update the file (on every node
>   in the cluster) and then force the analyzers to be re-created by
>   either of these actions

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to use **Custom Plugins** section to manage any custom plugins, scripts or dictionaries (stopwords, synonymns, etc.)
Steps:

- Create a zip file with the following directory structure:

  ```
  .

  |__ dictionaries

      |__ stopwords.txt
  ```
- Login to elastic cloud and go to **Custom Plugins** section
- Click on **Add Plugin**
- Fill in the relevant details and for the section **Plugin Type** select ***A bundle containing a dictionary or script***
- Click on **Create Plugin**
- Go back to the **Custom plugins** page and click on the new plugin you just added.
- Scroll to the bottom and upload the zip file created in first step.

Now you have to update your cluster so that its available to all the nodes. To do this follow the steps below:

- Click on **Deployment**
- Select your cluster/deployment form the page
- On the menu in the left click on **Edit**.
- Scroll to the section **Elasticsearch plugins and settings** on the
  page. Click on **Manage plugins and settings**.
- From the expanded list select your bundle (located under *Custom
  Plugins* section in the expanded list).
- On the bottom of the page click on **Save Changes**

Wait for the update activity to complete. Once completed you can now use stopwords.txt as below:

`"stopwords_path": "stopwords.txt"`

[Here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/index.html) is the complete elastic cloud documentation.
Documentation page for adding plugin/script/dictionary is [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-custom-bundles.html).

Comment: Great answer, thanks a lot. Is there any documentation page for this? If so, would you be able to add the link as reference please?

Comment: @Hooman I have added the documentation links. Also please accept the answer if it was helpful and solved your problem.

Comment: @Nishant After uploading zip file, do we need to do reindexing ?

Comment: @AbdulRazakAK Yes to update already indexed data you have to reindex.